# Ta-lib and pandas series not working with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, ta-lib

I'm new in Coding, so please be patient with me ;)
This is my code that didn't work, I'm trying several hours to solve it, but every time I got another error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import talib.abstract as ta


dfBTCUSD_1h = pd.read_csv('Bitfinex_BTCUSD_1h.csv', skiprows=1)
dfBTCUSD_1h.sort_values(by='Date') # This now sorts in date order


open = dfBTCUSD_1h.iloc[:,2]
high = dfBTCUSD_1h.iloc[:,3]
low  = dfBTCUSD_1h.iloc[:,4]
close =dfBTCUSD_1h.iloc[:,5]

short_ema = ta.EMA(close,timeperiod=10)
```

> `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

How can I edit the pandas series to a working file for ta-lib?

best regards

Comment: Is that the TypeError in it's entirety? I think that's very unlikely. Could you post the full error message please? Could you also isolate the line that gives you the error? Use breakpoints in your IDE, or comment out the OHLC section and check if the error still persists so that you can single out the line causing the error

Comment: File "C:\Users\maxi\Annaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 112, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
the error is the last line

Comment: Could you print the data type of the variable 'close' ?

Comment: it's a series object of pandas.core.series module

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supplying `code` to `ta.EMA`, do the following:

```
short_ema = ta.EMA(close.astype(float),timeperiod=10)
```

Talib functions usually take numpy arrays of dtype float as inputs

Comment: yeah, i thought i have to convert it. I tried it, but i got another error

  File "C:\Users\maxi\Annaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 112, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: Any chance you can print 'close' for me?

Comment: this is only a short part of them.

5629    4845.90
5630    4794.90
5631    4745.00
5632    4715.30
5633    4649.90
5634    4643.00
5635    4667.00
5636    4617.20
5637    4595.50
5638    4603.00
5639    4594.90
5640    4585.70
Name: Close, Length: 5641, dtype: float64